# Function that takes a list of strings and returns another specific list

Tags: python, list

I need to create a function that takes a list of words and then I want to check all the strings in that list and return another list of strings where the string first and last character are the same.

For example, given `input_list = ['a','aa','aba','abb']` output should be `['aa','aba']`.

Comment: Your example output is incorrect, it should include `'a'`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann not necessarily, maybe the OP doesn't want strings with `len` of `<=1`.

Comment: @user1823 Well then he needs to include that in the specification.

Comment: What is the issue then? Go ahead and try something.

Comment: @StefanPochmann sorry I forgot to mention that also the length should be more than 1 character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
def myfunc(lst):
     return [item for item in lst if len(item) > 1 and item[0] == item[-1]]
```

---

```
>>> myfunc(['a','aa','aba','abb'])
['aa', 'aba']
>>>
```

Comment: This is what I wanted thnx

Answer (score 2):

Just check the length is > 1, and see if the first  char `x[0]` is equal to the last char `x[-1]`:

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1 and x[0] == x[-1], lst)))
['aa', 'aba']
```

Or if you want a function:

```
f = lambda l:list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1 and x[0] == x[-1], l))

print(f(lst))
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to approach this, typically, is filtering a list, instead of seeing it as a different one, and define any function (either regular or lambda) to express what needs to be filtered on. That way your code is clear and easy to test and maintain:

```
filteredList = filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1 and x[0] == x[-1], myList)

#or:
def starts_and_ends_with_same_char(subject):
    return len(subject) > 1 and str[0] == subject[-1]

filteredList = filter(starts_and_ends_with_same_char, myList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Golfing a little:

```
>>> [s for s in lst if s[1:] and s[0] == s[-1]]
['aa', 'aba']
```